# I have query regarding larvel database migration and their model. is it necessary for big database

Tags: php, laravel, database, migration, schema

The query is if i have already a mysql database that contains more than 500+ tables now i want to shift project from smarty to laravel 10 now in laravel we use database migration create schema and their model to use it directly in our project. so my question is to is to worth to make schema of every table because it take lots of time and effort. After R&D i get the only benefits is version control, rollback and directly access to project Nothing else.

can any one explain do i create schema or not?

Comment: It depends on if you're keeping the same database or creating a new one. If you're keeping the same database and all of the data, then no, don't create a migration, unless you need to for new dev environments. If you're creating a new database, then create the migrations.

Comment: `the only benefits`...you don't value those benefits then? What other benefits would you want or expect?

Comment: If you have an existing database then you might want to also take a look at [squashing migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#squashing-migrations) in laravel. While it's not technically its purpose, this will generate a schema of your existing database and therefore you can start using migrations only for future database changes. The advantage of rolling back a database is worth doing this in my opinion, but rewriting the whole database in migration form is probably not worth it

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the reasons you've already listed, which IMHO are worth it in themselves, you need to consider that rewriting the database will provide you with the benefits of [Laravel naming conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) in managing the mapping of model objects to database tables and the resulting simplified and consistent access to data via Eloquent.